# Pandas dataframe to sparse representation

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, scikit-learn

I have a dense pandas dataframe.
I would like to get a sparse dataframe out of it where each value of the original dataframe would be the column of a 1 in the resulting sparse dataframe.

Example:

Original df:

```
    a b
0   5 3
1   2 6
```

Sparse df:

```
(0,3): 1
(0,5): 1
(1,2): 1
(1,6): 1
```

I do not care if in case of collision it is a 1 or the number of collision

I will then pass this df to sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression fit function (I am not sure which kind of sparse matrix would be accepted here)

What would be the appropriate approach ?

I can create it by hand (iterating over the row) but the dataframe is quite big so I am trying to find an efficient way of doing it.

Thanks

Comment: Try `sklearn.preprocessing.MultiLabelBinarizer` with `sparse = True`.

Comment: It works as expected but it is quite slow. Do you have any other idea which could do the same faster ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A much faster solution than the one proposed by @Dark is to use the csr_matrix constructor but the ones will sum up in case of redundancy which is ok for my case:

```
nrow = len(df.index)
ncol = len(df.columns)
indices = df.values.flatten()
data = np.full_like(indices, 1)
nelement = len(indices)
indptr = range(0, nelement+ncol, ncol)
result = csr_matrix((data, indices, indptr))
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on @Dark comment:

```
mlb = sklearn.preprocessing.MultiLabelBinarizer(sparse_output = True)
result = mlb.fit_transform(np.array[df])
```

fit_transform requires an iterable of iterables: [expalantion here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/6639)